# How to make recovery USB for MAC OS X with Windows?

Tags: macos

I recently bought Mac Mini with Mac OS X. I switched it on and noticed a few recommended updates. I installed them all. And here is the problem. My Mac is switching on properly. After switching keyboard works well, but there is nothing on the screen. After a small investigation I found possible source of a problem:

[Mac is unresponsive on startup after installing Thunderbolt Software Update 1.2r](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4303)

I tried to recover the system, but I haven't got Apple's wired keyboard. Wireless one connects too late to get to recovery mode. I treid another keyboards- "windows ones", but it didn't work (all combinations "start", "alt", "r", "ctrl"). I assume that system is booting properly so that I can't use internet recovery.

How can I make a Mac recovery USB without any Mac?

Comment: Yes. I tried many combinations, many times.

Comment: you may find tips here : http://forums.techguy.org/apple-mac/1063377-making-bootable-usb-mac-os.html